# 100% Disk Usage all the time - laptop keeps freezing whenever it spikes up

Tags: windows-8, freeze

I was wondering if anyone can help me? I'm very tempted to "restore to factory settings" and just completely restart everything...Will this work?

I have literally tried everything. From changing the power plan to deactivatingt some services. Nothing worked. I don't know if it is my actual hard drives fault? Or something I downloaded.

I also, started up Malwarebytes and it found nothing. Windows Defender came up with nothing as well. I Really want to just restore my laptop to factory settings.

My Disk Drive also spikes up to 100% whenever I come out of sleep mode. Currently I'm only able to use my laptop for about 5 minutes before the regular 5% Disk Space goes up to 100%.

Comment: Long shot, you wouldnt perhaps own a Lenovo with an SSHD?

Comment: I own a dell Inspiron 15r

Comment: When its at 100% what are the read and write speeds?

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the 100% Disk usage: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the potential causes may be some type of malware that could be eating up your computer resources but it does not have to be the case, many badly designed drivers and programs can cause such behaviour as well.
To be absolutely sure the issue is caused or is not caused by malware I would advise to scan with few more programs such as SpyBot Search & Destroy and SUPERAntiMalware, I can only post two links in single answer but just type the names into Google and their websites should appear, they are both freeware programs.
If all these programs find nothing/do not fix the problem, download external Live CD/Rescue ISOs such as [Kaspersky Rescue CD](http://support.kaspersky.co.uk/viruses/rescuedisk) or [Bitdefender Rescue CD](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/), scans performed by those programs will take reasonably longer in comparison to anti-malware programs but they will be much more detailed and trustworthy.
You will find those programs are inside of ISO files - you will need program such as ISOtoUSB to burn them onto the USB and boot from BIOS level (alternatively you can burn them onto a CD but I do not recommend that).
Of course if you do not have enough time, restoring to factory settings should work as Windows will be restored from back-up partition in original, untouched state. Be sure to back-up your files such as photos and documents before performing it though as Windows may not copy all the files you would like to retain.