# Got really annoying Virus

Tags: windows-10, virus

I've got the problem that my little sister got an virus on my laptop, so I had a BSoD all the time, he didn't even boot windows. After a lot changes windows booted and all my data was there too, but now regulary I'm getting a new blue screen. Every time a other error. I think it's an virus who infects all my dll's. I can't even start programs like Firefox... need help how to solve that... can't open anti virus program - seems infected too, on reinstall I got BSoD again and crash...
My local time changed too.
Got Windows 10 Pro 64x
Thank you

Comment: IMO the best solution is to wipe the hard drive clean and re-install Windows from scratch. If you don't know how to do this yourself, get someone who does know to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by reinstall, did you mean after reinstalling Firefox or whole OS?
If you have not reinstalled your OS or reinstalled but not erased/formatted your disk yet then have a look at this, [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/984837/100-disk-usage-all-the-time-laptop-keeps-freezing-whenever-it-spikes-up/984858#984858).
The steps I have given there might be applied to your case as well.
If you cannot run programs then skip the steps with Windows malware scanners and use the LiveCD scanners listed there (you will probably to download those on another computer if yours is crashing so much).
If you already erased everything that was on your disk when crashes started occurring and made a clean OS installation then the only cause for BSoDs I can see is the hardware fault.
Especially very random and unpredictable nature of the errors seems to point to RAM memory problems.
To diagnose RAM, you will need memory diagnostic program such as [Memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/).

Comment: Just by reinstalling Firefox. Got now my virus scanning tool reinstalled from lockscreen and now do a virus scan from the lock screen too. But I see yout point, I'm going to do a memtest - thank u